# java- how to use hashmaps for response data = a struct of keyphrases each with a single item list of the original keyphrase

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to connect via an XML RPC call to an API that takes as input a list of phrases, and gives as output-- "Echoes back a struct of keyphrases each with a single item list of the original keyphrase."

I am trying to use regular hashmap parsing code in the following way--

```
  hMap = (HashMap<String, Integer>) untypedResult;

        Set set = hMap.entrySet();

        Iterator i = set.iterator();

        while(i.hasNext()){
          Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
          resp.getWriter().println(me.getKey() + " : " + me.getValue() );
        }
```

The output that I am getting is as follows--

Response for GetThesaurusKeyPhrases----
mp3 : [Ljava.lang.Object;@76c3358b
britney spears : [Ljava.lang.Object;@9f07597

How do I obtain the values correctly? What I think is that I should parse each value (the me.getvalue part) correctly... but I am confused on how to go about doing this... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They're arrays of objects; which agrees with what the doc says. Get the first element and cast it. I seriously doubt it's an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to cast each key and value, ie `(String)me.getKey()` and see what you get.

From the snippet you've posted, it is possible that the `HashMap<String, Integer>` in your cast is incorrect.  The original HashMap may have been defined as simply a `HashMap` or `HashMap<Object, Object>` since your variable name is `untypedResult`. I tried the following and it works as expected:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> hMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    hMap.put("Hi1", new Integer(1));
    hMap.put("Hi2", new Integer(2));
    hMap.put("Hi3", new Integer(3));
    hMap.put("Hi4", new Integer(4));
    Set set = hMap.entrySet();
    Iterator i = set.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
        System.out.println(me.getKey().getClass().getName() + " : " + me.getValue().getClass().getName() );
        System.out.println(me.getKey() + " : " + me.getValue() );
    }
}
```

The output for this block is:

```
java.lang.String : java.lang.Integer
Hi2 : 2
java.lang.String : java.lang.Integer
Hi1 : 1
java.lang.String : java.lang.Integer
Hi4 : 4
java.lang.String : java.lang.Integer
Hi3 : 3
```